# How to read this kind of format

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

Suppose I have an input like this, one cell each line:

```
[0,0]
[0,2]
[0,4]
[2,4]
[4,4]
```

I've managed to read them one by one using something like `[%d,%d]` and get the output like:

```
cell1: row: 0, col:0
cell1: row: 0, col:2
```

then I have another input like this

```
[0,0]->[0,1]->
[0,2]->[0,3]->
[0,4]->[1,4]->
[2,4]->[3,4]->
[4,4]->[5,4]
```

How do I read the input without being interrupted by the arrow '`->'`?

Comment: Post the code you've tried to use to parse the `[]->...` format.

Comment: I guess the `[%d,%d]` is supposed to be a `scanf` format. Please [edit] your question and add a small program that demonstrates how you read the input and print the output for the first input example.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, quick and cheap solution: Scan everything up to an opening bracket and don't care what it is. Then scan the actual data. Repeat.

```
int x, y;

scanf("%*[^[]");            // ignore everything up to the first [

while (scanf(" [%d ,%d]", &x, &y) == 2) {
    printf("[%d, %d]\n", x, y);

    scanf("%*[^[]");        // ignore stuff between ] and [
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[%d,%d]->"
```

Use one whitespace in your format string to skip any number of whitespace (including newline...) in your input.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have input lines like

```
[0,0]
[0,2]
[0,4]
```

and you are successfully reading them using a `fscanf` call like

```
fscanf(ifp, " [%d,%d]", &row, &col);
```

If that's so, and if you have another input format

```
[0,0]->[0,1]->
[0,2]->[0,3]->
[0,4]->[1,4]->
```

why can't you just use something like

```
fscanf(ifp, " [%d,%d]->[%d,%d]->", &row1, &col1, &row2, &col2);
```

I suppose you could also use

```
fscanf(ifp, " [%d,%d]->", &row, &col);
```

which would require two calls to read each line.

P.S. Obligatory `scanf` reminders:

1. Remember to always check the return value from `scanf` and `fscanf` to make sure the expected inputs were matched.  (I conspicuously failed to follow this advice in the code fragments in this answer.)
2. Even though it often seems like *the thing* to use, `fscanf` is usually a poor tool for the job, and it can be more trouble than it's worth to get it do do what you actually want.  You can [consider using alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf).